# How do I change the Report Designer Ruler unit from Inches to centimetres?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reporting-services

A simple (I hope) question, I'm using Visual Studio, I create a new report in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio. In layout view the ruler is in inches, I would like to change it to centimetres.

**Update 1**

Changing the regional settings worked.

Is it not possible to do this without changing the regional settings? I would have hoped this would be a setting within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Regional Settings from English (United States) to English (Australia)

ie through Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Settings.

Answer (score 6):

Try the Windows Regional Settings?

Comment: This is a question or comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to change the Windows regional settings. You can do it via the report properties.

I have v15 of the ReportBuilder. You can open it as in the picture:

[image]

In order to display the "**Report**" properties, not other object ones (Body, a chart of a Textbox field).

Unselect anything in your report in order to have the report properties visible.

And attention the setting is for that report only, you will need to change it for every report you have.

Comment: This is the answer!. It also works in the SSRS Query Designer which comes with SQL Server 2016 (v 15.0.19611.0)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how to set this in BIDS, but if you open the RDL file in a text editor, e.g. notepad, toward the the bottom of the file you should see:

```
  <Language>en-GB</Language>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>b5fa3be2-c9a8-41b7-bb70-df2e2e9e86ec</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Change rd:ReportUnitType to

```
 <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, at least in the 9.0 edition. 
Bring the record properties (Report/report properties) and there you can choose the measures to be in inches or centimeters. That includes the rulers and the measures of the elements of the report if you decide to input them yourself with the properties panel.

Comment: I have the v15 there is nothing like that in File->options