# How can I use pixels in Visual Studio instead of inches?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, bids

I'm making reports in Business Intelligence Designer Studio (VS 2005).  My reports will be viewed primarily on the screen, and I'd like to change my ruler to pixels instead of inches.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

format is:

1pt = 1 pixel
1pc = 1 percent
1cm = 1 centimeter
1in = 1 inch

Comment: ruler stays in inches no matter what I do.

Comment: I reread your question and I think I misunderstood it. I believe what you are looking for can be achieved by changing your regional setting under windows:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604773/how-do-i-change-the-report-designer-ruler-unit-from-inches-to-centimetres

Comment: That would change me from inches to centimeters, but I don't want cm.  I want inches, and pixels on the ruler.